# Sending notifications according to database value changes

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, push-notification, azure-sql-database, mpns

I am working on a vendor portal. An owner of a shop will login and in the navigation bar (similar to facebook) I would like the number of items sold to appear INSTANTLY, WITHOUT ANY REFRESH. In facebook, new notifications pop up immediately. I am using sql azure as my database. Is it possible to note a change in the database and INSTANTLY INFORM the user?

Part 2 of my project will consist of a mobile phone app for the vendor. In this app I, too , would like to have the same notification mechanism. In this case, would I be correct if I search on push notifications and apply them?

At the moment my main aim is to solve the problem in paragraph 1. I am able to retrieve the number of notifications, but how on earth is it possible to show the changes INSTANTLY? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define what INSTANT means to you. For some, it means within a second 90% of the time. For others, they would be happy to have a 10-20 second gap on average. And more importantly, you need to understand the implications of your requirements; in other words, is it worth it to have near zero wait time for your business? The more relaxed your requirements, the cheaper it will be to build and the easier it will be to maintain.

You should know that having near-time notification can be very expensive in terms of computing and locking resources. The more you refresh, the more web roundtrips are needed (even if they are minimal in this case). Having data fresh to the second can also be costly to the database because you are potentially creating a high volume of requests, which in turn could affect otherwise good performing requests. For example, if your website runs with 1000 users logged on, you may need 1000 database requests per second (assuming that's your definition of INSTANT), which could in turn create a throttling condition in SQL Azure if not designed properly.

An approach I used in the past, for a similar requirement (although the precision wasn't to the second; more like to the minute) was to load all records from a table in memory in the local website cache. A background thread was locking and refreshing the in memory data for all records in one shot. This allowed us to reduce the database traffic by a factor of a thousand since the data presented on the screen was coming from the local cache and a single database connection was needed to refresh the cache (per web server). Because we had multiple web servers, and we needed the data to be exactly the same on all web servers within a second of each other, we synchronized the requests of all the web servers to refresh the cache every minute. Putting this together took many hours, but it allowed us to build a system that was highly scalable.

The above technique may not work for your requirements, but my point is that the higher the need for fresh data, the more design/engineering work you will need to make sure your system isn't too impacted by the freshness requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing such knowledge. I know that this will be quite expensive; but let us say that the business example was more sort of a hypotethical situation. Imagine that these must be A MUST as a requirement. By INSTANT I mean that once a change is inserted into the database, the related user is immediately notified. I have heard about polling and pushing sql cache dependancies, (see part 2)

Comment: but from what we've searched; these cannot be implemented on SQL Azure databases; thus we are looking for another mechanism; the same type of mechanism such as the PUSH notification for mobile apps, where once a notification is inserted, it is immediately sent to the phone. Now I would like to apply this to the web. Thank you for your time and patience!